# SVN: Redo changes

Tags: svn

SVN beginner here:

Let's say I committed a file: revision 20. There were some problems with it so I rolled back svn merge -r 20:19 /somepath and then committed the old changes back. Time goes on and other teammates contribute and now we're at revision 40. While my teammates have been working, I've been tweaking my old code and now I'm ready to add it back. The only problem is, HEAD no longer has my changes, so svn update deletes my code or results in conflicts. If I try a reverse merge, it deletes all the code that my teammates have been working on. How do I merge my code with the HEAD so it leaves code my teammates have added untouched and code that I've added untouched?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand the issue here. Let's say there's only a single file called `foo.txt` in your project.

- In Revision 20, you made a change in `foo.txt`.
- In Revision 30, you realize that your change was a complete booboo and you need to take it out.

Easy enough:

```
$ svn -c -20 $REPO   # Same as your -r20:19
$ svn commit -m"Removing Revision 20 from Revision 31 (the next one)"
```

Now, here's the part where things get cloudy...

Let's assume you checked out revision #31, (the revision where you backed out your changes). You sit here and add your changes back in and now they work. However, everyone else has moved on to Revision #40. What do you do?

```
$ svn update   # Updates from Revision 30 to Revision 40, but keeps your changes
$ svn commit   # Now creates Revision 41 with your changes and your friends' changes.
```

That should take care of it.